# Is it possible to write a small (5 line - or more) batch file in the Windows Command Line?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I was wanting to make a really quick `netstat` batch file that would do the `netstat -a` command for an infinite amount of time, and thought it would make more sense if I just made it in CMD, without needing to make a batch file and do the extra steps.

I did the following code hoping it'd work similarly to a Linux machine or a simple Python command-line IDE, but it didn't work:

```
:start
echo foobar
goto start
```

Comment: use a single command: `for /l %a in (1,0,1) do @echo foobar`

Comment: Note also that the `@echo foobar` above could become many lines of code enclosed in parentheses, `for ... do ( multiple things )`

Comment: Just note that if you run an infinite loop in batch, you _must_ include a `timeout` of 3 seconds or more to prevent your CPU usage from hitting 100%.

Comment: @Stephan: the numbers in parentheses are not necessary. If they are omitted, the loop never ends: `for /L %a in () do @echo foobar`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`for /l %a in (1,0,1) do cls && netstat -an`

Name resolving disable due speed.

Comment: Perhaps because this answer is a copy of the solution given by @Stephan in a comment one day earlier...